# How do I truncate a field and append "..." to it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out a select statement that will truncate a field value to 100 characters and add ... to the end of it so like:

HundredLetterSentence becomes HundredLetter Sen... or something like that. Here is the select statement from my stored procedure. I'm kinda stuck from here. The Select TOP(1) Description is where I want to do the truncation.

```
SELECT      [TI].[TicketID]
        ,   CAST([TI].[Subject] AS VARCHAR(100)) [Subject]
        ,   [TA].[DueDate]
        ,   CAST(
                    (   SELECT 
                        TOP(1)      SUBSTRING(Description, 0, 100)
                        FROM        Comment 
                        WHERE       TicketID = [TI].[TicketID] 
                        ORDER BY    CommentDate DESC
                    ) AS VARCHAR(100)
                ) AS [Description]
FROM        [dbo].[Ticket]      [TI]
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Task]        [TA] 
ON          [TI].[TicketID]     = [TA].[TicketID]
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Task_Status] [TS] 
ON          [TA].[StatusID]     = [TS].[StatusID]
WHERE       [TI].[IsDeleted]    = 0 
AND         [TS].[IsDeleted]    = 0
AND         [TS].[Status]       = 'Open'
AND         [TI].[AssigneeView] IS NULL
AND         [TI].[AssignedTo]   = @AssignedTo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will work is something like -

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN (LEN(Table1.LongText) < 100) THEN Table1.LongText
           ELSE SUBSTRING(Table1.LongText,1, 97) + '...'
       END AS [Description]
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Oops - reread the post and saw you said "truncate to 100 characters", I made the total length of the field 100 characters :)  You can replace the 97 with 100 (or whatever length you want to clip

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method here would be to create a [User Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214363%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (UDF).

In this UDF you would have something like:

```
IF LEN(@Value)>100
BEGIN
   SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@Value, 0, 100) + '...'
END
RETURN @Value
```

Then in your `SELECT` statement you would do:

```
SELECT [TI].[TicketID], dbo.TruncateString([TI].[Subject]) .....
```

Comment: I actually wouldn't recommend a UDF in the SELECT list to perform a simple string operation. Why? Well, fire up a trace and see what happens when you do that against a table with many rows. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH x (d, tid, rn) AS
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, 1, 100) + CASE
    WHEN LEN(Description) > 100 THEN '...' ELSE '' END,
    TicketID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY TicketID ORDER BY CommentDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.Comment
)
SELECT [TI].[TicketID], 
  CAST([TI].[Subject] AS VARCHAR(100)) [Subject], 
  [TA].[DueDate], 
  x.d AS [Description]
    FROM     [dbo].[Ticket] [TI]
             INNER JOIN [dbo].[Task] [TA] ON [TI].[TicketID] = [TA].[TicketID]
             INNER JOIN [dbo].[Task_Status] [TS] ON [TA].[StatusID] = [TS].[StatusID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x ON TI.TicketID = x.tid
    AND x.rn = 1 -- oops, forgot this important part
    WHERE    [TI].[IsDeleted] = 0 AND
             [TS].[IsDeleted] = 0 AND
             [TS].[Status] = 'Open' AND
             [TI].[AssigneeView] IS NULL AND
             [TI].[AssignedTo] = @AssignedTo;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need all fields to have '...' or only the ones who are actually bigger than 100 chars.
If you need all, you can do something like:

```
select substring(name,0,97)+'...' from...
```